USB to Serial - CH340 vs Silabs or FTDI
I was researching the CH340 USB-UART converter and found that the CH340G variant has a speed range of 50bps to 2mbps. However, the datasheet does not provide extensive information regarding the tx/rx buffer sizes.
Looking at the famous FTDI, FT2232H, we can see 4Kbytes for TX and 4Kbytes for RX, respectively.
Looking at Silabs CP2102, we can see 640 bytes for TX and 576 bytes for RX.
My issue is, does anyone know the buffer size of the CH340 (for TX and RX)?
Regarding that, in my application, I noticed real-time packet loss using the CH340, but when I switched to a Silabs or FTDI, the fault was resolved. My intuition is the buffer size, but I would like to hear about anything such as driver issues (I'm running Windows 10) or counterfeit parts. Anyone can help on this discussion?
using an application with CH340 to control a RS485 transceiver between a two-point wired devices. Using low data rate of 19200bps.
